# Error on webpack: can't resolve 'xlsx'. Bundle is not generated

Tags: webpack

I am working on a project that must be production ready but my webpack (I use for several other projects) is not working due to a download dependency. I need help.

This is my package.json file:

```
{
"name": "beanworks",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "accounts payable app",
"main": "index.js",
"repository": {
"type": "github",
"url": "https://github.com/xumes/beanworks-accounts-payable"
},
"scripts": {
"test": "standard",
"client": "webpack -w --config webpack.config.js",
"server": "nodemon index.js",
"dev": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"npm run client\" \"npm run server\"",
"start": "node index.js",
"beforeInstall": "webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js"
},
"keywords": [
    "beanworks",
    "xero",
    "invoice",
    "node.js",
    "react.js",
    "webpack"
],
"author": "Reginaldo Santos (reginaldosantos.br@gmail.com)",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-data-export": "^0.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-promise": "^0.6.0",
    "session-memory-store": "^0.2.2",
    "socket.io": "^2.1.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.1.1",
    "xero-node": "^3.0.16"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-regenerator": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "concurrently": "^3.6.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.5",
    "standard": "^12.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.7",
    "webpack": "^4.12.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.3"
},
"engines": {
    "node": "8.11.3"
    }
}
```

Here is the webpack.common.js:

```
const path = require('path')
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

const cleanOptions = {
  verbose: true,
  dry: false
}

const APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, './src/client')

module.exports = {
  entry: `${APP_DIR}/index.js`,
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(jsx|js)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              cacheDirectory: true
            }
          }
        ],
        exclude: [/node_modules/]
      },
      {
        test: /(\.css|.scss)$/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'style-loader' },
          { loader: 'css-loader' },
          { loader: 'sass-loader' }
        ],
        exclude: [/node_modules/]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|svg|ttf|jpg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        exclude: [/node_modules/]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),     cleanOptions),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'config/index.html')
    })
  ]
}
```

the the webpack.config.prod.js, but the error is happening on the commong file above.

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')

const common = require('./webpack.common.js')

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'production',
  stats: {
    colors: false,
    hash: true,
    timings: true,
    assets: true,
    chunks: true,
    chunkModules: true,
    modules: true,
    children: true
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJSPlugin({
        sourceMap: true,
        uglifyOptions: {
          compress: {
            inline: false
          }
        }
      })
    ],
    runtimeChunk: false,
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        default: false,
        commons: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          name: 'vendor_app',
          chunks: 'all',
          minChunks: 2
        }
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
      }
    })
  ]
})
```

Here is the output with the error I am receiving:

```
reginaldosantos$ npm run beforeInstall

> beanworks@1.0.0 beforeInstall             /Users/reginaldosantos/dev/lab/
> webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js

clean-webpack-plugin:     /Users/reginaldosantos/dev/lab/dist has been removed.
Hash: e12ecfae20b56e678e04
Version: webpack 4.28.2
Time: 27814ms
Built at: 12/26/2018 10:40:55 AM
 3 assets
Entrypoint main = bundle.js
chunk    {0} bundle.js (main) 2.1 MiB [entry] [rendered]
  [10] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 472 bytes {0} [built]
  [28] ./node_modules/react-redux/es/index.js + 19 modules 36.2 KiB     {0} [built]
       |    20 modules
  [64] ./src/client/actions/index.js 526 bytes {0} [built]
 [122] ./src/client/index.js 1010 bytes {0} [built]
 [131] (webpack)/buildin/harmony-module.js 573 bytes {0} [built]
 [146] ./src/client/containers/Refresh.js 4.17 KiB {0} [built]
 [167] ./src/client/images/vendors.jpg 82 bytes {0} [built]
 [168] ./src/client/images/accts.jpg 82 bytes {0} [built]
 [169] ./src/client/containers/Vendors.js 6.75 KiB {0} [built]
 [176] (webpack)/buildin/amd-define.js 85 bytes {0} [built]
 [177] (webpack)/buildin/amd-options.js 80 bytes {0} [built]
 [289] ./src/client/containers/Accounts.js 7.17 KiB {0} [built]
 [291] ./src/client/reducers/index.js 433 bytes {0} [built]
 [292] ./src/client/reducers/reducer_xero.js 479 bytes {0} [built]
 [293] ./node_modules/react-router-dom/es/index.js + 34 modules 80.3     KiB {0} [built]
       |    35 modules
     + 279 hidden modules
 [10] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 472 bytes {0} [built]
 [28] ./node_modules/react-redux/es/index.js + 19 modules 36.2 KiB     {0} [built]
      |    20 modules
 [64] ./src/client/actions/index.js 526 bytes {0} [built]
[122] ./src/client/index.js 1010 bytes {0} [built]
[131] (webpack)/buildin/harmony-module.js 573 bytes {0} [built]
[146] ./src/client/containers/Refresh.js 4.17 KiB {0} [built]
[167] ./src/client/images/vendors.jpg 82 bytes {0} [built]
[168] ./src/client/images/accts.jpg 82 bytes {0} [built]
[169] ./src/client/containers/Vendors.js 6.75 KiB {0} [built]
[176] (webpack)/buildin/amd-define.js 85 bytes {0} [built]
[177] (webpack)/buildin/amd-options.js 80 bytes {0} [built]
[289] ./src/client/containers/Accounts.js 7.17 KiB {0} [built]
[291] ./src/client/reducers/index.js 433 bytes {0} [built]
[292] ./src/client/reducers/reducer_xero.js 479 bytes {0} [built]
[293] ./node_modules/react-router-dom/es/index.js + 34 modules 80.3     KiB {0} [built]
      |    35 modules
    + 279 hidden modules

ERROR in ./node_modules/tempa-xlsx/ods.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'xlsx' in     '/Users/reginaldosantos/dev/lab/node_modules/tempa-    xlsx'
 @ ./node_modules/tempa-xlsx/ods.js 13:21-41
 @ ./node_modules/tempa-xlsx/xlsx.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-data-    export/dist/ExcelPlugin/components/ExcelFile.js
 @ ./node_modules/react-data-export/dist/index.js
 @ ./src/client/components/Download.js
 @ ./src/client/components/App.js
 @ ./src/client/index.js
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
     1 asset
    Entrypoint undefined = index.html
    chunk    {0} index.html 530 KiB [entry] [rendered]
     [0] ./node_modules/html-webpack-    plugin/lib/loader.js!./config/index.html 2.29 KiB {0} [built]
     [2] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 472 bytes {0} [built]
     [3] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 497 bytes {0} [built]
         + 1 hidden module
    [0] ./node_modules/html-webpack-    plugin/lib/loader.js!./config/index.html 2.29 KiB {0} [built]
    [2] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 472 bytes {0} [built]
    [3] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 497 bytes {0} [built]
        + 1 hidden module
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! beanworks@1.0.0 beforeInstall: `webpack --config     webpack.config.prod.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the beanworks@1.0.0 beforeInstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely     additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/reginaldosantos/.npm/_logs/2018-12-    26T12_40_55_827Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I am not proud of that but I fixed the issue by replacing the "Download to Excel" dependency.
I am using **react-excel-workbook** instead of *react-data-export*.
My Webpack is working fine and generating the bundle for production.

Comment: I use react-data-export and work fine after install xlsx package
(```npm i xlsx```)